# Index was out of range must be less than or negative

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm having a problem about this Index was out of range and I really don't know what is solution for this. This is the code.

```
Sub insert()
    Dim dt As DataTable

    Try

        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            exec("select * from TBL_SUMMARY1")
            dt = exec("insert into TBL_SUMMARY1 values('" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(14).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(15).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(16).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(17).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(18).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(19).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(20).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(21).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(22).Value & "','" & Date.Today & "' )")

        Next
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Insert Successfuly")
        TextBox1.Text = ""

        DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

also here when importing some excel files and hide the other data.

```
 Dim op As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim partfile As String
    Try
        op.Filter = "XlS Files (*.xls)|*.xls|Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
        If op.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            TextBox1.Text = op.FileName
            partfile = TextBox1.Text

            con = New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= '" & partfile & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR = yes""")
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Summary$]", con)
            da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Myfile")
            ds = New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds)
            ds.Tables(0).Rows.RemoveAt(0)
            ds.Tables(0).Rows.RemoveAt(0)
            ds.Tables(0).Rows.RemoveAt(0)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
            DataGridView1.Refresh()
            con.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

After importing this will pop [Sample error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqFE6.png)

Comment: You need to specify where in the code the error occurs. As for what you can do, the first thing to do is determine what index value is being used. The second is to determine what the valid range is.  You need to learn how to debug code rather than just reading it and hoping something jumps out at you.  You could start [here](https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets5p6.html) and then search the web for more information on the subject.

Comment: First one - are there 23 columns in your grid?

Comment: Try `For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem are solved already, I just solved this by saving the Excel from old to new data inside of excel. I don't know if this solve to the others.

Answer (score 0):

You must be sure of the number of columns in the database, you must include the column index (0) in count
After confirming the number of columns, you must make sure that the number of columns in () equals the number of columns or less in the database table, and that there is no conflict of value greater than each other or a difference in types of variables

Else if 
Give me a picture of the table in the database